# How to account for Windows newline ( \r\n ) while setting carat position on textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea, newline

I have been working on some code that modifies the carat position as you type in a textarea. With most browsers, a newline is "\n", but on IE 8 and down, a newline is "\r\n", giving it twice the length of a normal newline. How can I account for this discrepancy when setting my carat position? I have found this [resource](http://www.sitepoint.com/line-endings-in-javascript/) but I am not sure how to implement it to rectify my issue. I thought it'd be as simple as counting the number of newlines after stripping "\r\n" to "\n", and then multiplying that amount by 2 and adding that to my carat position, but it does not work.

Fiddle: http://bit.ly/TAQxiV

Lines 67-116 are used for getting and setting the carat position and textarea content.

Script in question: http://jakiestfu.github.com/Behave.js/

Comment: Properly done, both the input (character count) and the output (cursor position) must be larger in IE, so it is not clear why you would need any special handling. Maybe you could clarify what your exact problem is?

Comment: At any rate, if you strip all `\r` from the text, you should only add their number once.

Comment: I've tried stripping the \r from the editors value via the get method, but it still does not work right. If you were to try that Fiddle in IE8, you'll see the problem, the carat is almost never inserted in the right space

Comment: The fiddle is too long to be of much use in debugging, especially if one does not have IE8 (as I assume most people don't). You should find which part exactly is returning wrong results, and create a test case.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might be to test for those specific versions of IE and modify some variable to be `2` in those case, and `1` the rest of the time.

You can use the `BrowserDetect` object to do this.

```
BrowserDetect.browser // the name of the browser
BrowserDetect.version // the version of the browser
```

Comment: Browser detection is a bad practice, you should use feature detection instead (just match for `\r\n` in the text).

Comment: While I agree that browser detection is suboptimal in most applications, feature detection may be an issue when concerned *only* with certain versions of Internet Explorer. As long as there is a feature that differentiates IE 8 and below from 9, 10, and beyond, then, sure, go for it.